# How to implement nested location and store it in a database with PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a filterable magazines database with PHP and MYSQL.

I've done everything but I have issues with the location part. I want to show a nested select for filtering the magazines by location like this:

[image: Filterable location]

I have a `magazine` table on the MySQL database which has a `location` column. Sometimes it's possible a magazine has multiple locations. Should I create a separate table for locations?
If I want to show all the locations statically (only with HTML), there are a lot of countries with no magazines. I just want to show the locations has at least one magazine.

Could you explain and give advice on how to implement it?

Comment: Please, add some code of your attempts first. You can start with the code for get your `magazines`, from database, and then you can start thinking in how to render they in your page.

Comment: @AndréWalker Thank you for your comment. Actually, I have a problem with the back-end. I don't know what is the best way to achieve this. 
Each magazine has a location and sometimes multiple locations. I don't know that use a separate table for them or do it statically. I can just put a string of locations on the location column in the magazine table but if I do that, I have to iterate the whole database to know which countries I have.

Comment: For nested locations - you need to learn how to store hierarchical data in relational databases: https://drib.tech/programming/hierarchical-data-in-relational-databases

When it comes to possibility to have same magazine in different locations - it is a separate problem. I would create additional associative/connection/join table between locations and magazines. For example you have `location` table, you have `magazine` table (remove location from it), and create a new table `location_magazine` which can contain, at minimum 2 columns (`location.id` and `magazine.id`).

Comment: @AndréWalker Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each location you add `is_a_group` and `parent` data. Each location must have unique ID(like every other data in the database).

If you want to create location(or something else) that is collection of other things(like `Asia` on provided image), set `is_a_group` to `1`.
When you load data with `is_a_group = 1`, show all data with `parent` equal to ID of data where `is_a_group` is set to `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it's a great idea. But, if I create a table for locations, I have to create a relational table to set relations between magazines and their locations because sometimes a magazine has more than one location. Is this the efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can use `1:n` relationship (one magazine can have n locations)
For later data processing you will need joins https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp